# How to Create a Apple Music User Token in react native

Tags: react-native, apple-music

I'm trying to access my personal Apple Music library. When I followed the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens) they said we need to generate **Music User Token** and pass the music user token in the header. How can I do that in the react-native. Not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Music API doesn't let you manually ask for a user token (as far as I know). You have to use their proprietary frameworks to do that.

- In iOS, it's as simple as calling a framework function.
- In Android, the SDK has to be downloaded and added to the project (and then a function call to get the user token once you have it)
- For JS, refer to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs).

It tells you to embed MusicKit JS into your webpage/JS program and other things like wrapping its `authorize` method.

The UI flow is handled for you. A pop-up for the user's AppleID and password will be presented for the user to fill in.